# In search of nested hyperlinks: how to achieve this effect?

Tags: html, user-interface, hyperlink, nested, anchor

It's often we come across a use-case which appears to be prohibited by a specification.

As we all know, nested hyperlinks are prohibited by the HTML spec. Unlike most other parts of the spec this is a hard requirement as a browser treats the beginning of a new hyperlink as the end of the old one.

**Why might you want to use nested hyperlinks?**
If, like me, you like your HTML to be particularly terse, it's not uncommon to find yourself using anchors as block-level elements to define a large clickable area. Large clickable areas are good for usability reasons: I'm sure we've all been in those embaressing client meetings where the client is trying to click fruitlessly on something which looks like a button but can't because your anchor defines a text-level span, and not the surrounding button-looking parent block. Having big things to click on instead of small things just makes things easier, y'know.

Within our large clickable blocks, its not uncommon for a designer to want to nest some smaller modifier link related to the parent block but not mapped to it. To great examples are like this "Click here to go to  or click here to go to  (which thing is a child of". Or better: "Click here to go to  or click here to a child of that ", such as a comments section or other internal anchor".

**Example #1: Child of linked object**
[image: Example #1: Child of linked object]

Here we have the canonical example for why nested anchors are useful. The entire card is clickable for useability reasons and takes the user to the linked article. It is composed of a single block-level anchor element styled with the theme framework's horizontal layout classes. The comment counter symbol (far-left bottom) must take the user directly to the linked page's #comments section.

Here's a markup example:

```
<a class="row" href="article.html">
    <img src="" class="col-4">
    <div class="col-2">
         <div class="category">Top stop</div>
         <h1>Article title</h1>
         <time>Date</time>
         <div class="desc">Article lead</div>
         <a class="commentbml" href="article.html#comments">2</a>
    </div>
</a>
```

Eagle-eyed observers will notice that the browser will interpret the above HTML like this:

```
<a class="row" href="article.html">
    <img src="" class="col-4">
</a>
<div class="col-2">
    <div class="category">Top stop</div>
    <h1>Article title</h1>
    <time>Date</time>
     <div class="desc">Article lead</div>
    <a class="commentbml" href="article.html#comments">2</a>
 </div>
```

**Example #2: Category of linked object**

[image: Example #2: Category of linked object]

The link card media box is composed of a single outer  element styled at block-level. This aid useability by making the entire surface of the card clickable. However, the NEWS link top-right should take the user to that category. As well as providing a quick navigation aid, this is consistent with other instances of the article category motif on the site.

Here's a markup example.

```
<a class="box" href="article.html">
    <a class="category" href="article-category.html">News</a>
    <img src="">
    <div class="caption">Article title</div>
</a>
```

And again, browsers will interpret the above like this:

```
<a class="box" href="article.html"></a>
<a class="category" href="article-category.html">News</a>
<img src="">
<div class="caption">Article title</div>
```

**So. If a client gave you this brief, what would be the best way to accomplish it, given the deficiencies of the spec?**

Comment: What (representative, "[mcve]") HTML are you using? What layout in particular do you want to achieve? This can be emulated with HTML and CSS, or implemented with JavaScript. Which would you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, with HTML and CSS alone (since you've indicated no willingness to use JavaScript) is to emulate the nesting appearance; simply wrap the containing `<a>` element within an outer container, such as a `<div>`, position that container, using CSS, to a non-static property-value and position the 'nested' elements using absolute positioning.

For this I insert the elements to 'nest' as adjacent siblings of the original containing `<a>` element, to give:

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
Block-level link filling the enclosing &lt;div&gt; element, linking to Stack Overflow.
</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help" class="pseudoNested">Help center</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve" class="pseudoNested">MCVE</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/company/about" class="pseudoNested">About SO</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the following (basic, all-aesthetics removed) CSS:

```
.item {
  /* a defined height to allow the child <a> element to
     fill the height of its parent, using 'height: 100%' */
  height: 10em;

  /* to allow descendants to be position in relation to this
     element, any value other than 'static' would suffice for
     this: */
  position: relative;
}

.item a {
  /* to horizontally fill its parent: */
  display: block;
  /* to vertically fill its parent: */
  height: 100%;
}

.item > a {
  padding-right: 10em;
}

.item ul {
  /* moving the element(s) out of the normal flow of
     of the document, and positioning according to
     its closest non-static ancestor: */
  position: absolute;

  /* adjust to taste: */
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```css
.item {
  height: 10em;
  position: relative;
}
.item a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
.item > a {
  padding-right: 10em;
}
.item ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
Block-level link filling the enclosing &lt;div&gt; element, linking to Stack Overflow.
</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help" class="pseudoNested">Help center</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve" class="pseudoNested">MCVE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/company/about" class="pseudoNested">About SO</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With some basic aesthetics re-introduced, this can be improved to the following to make things more visible:

```css
.item {
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqZksl.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  height: 10em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.item a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.item > a {
  padding-right: 10em;
}
.item ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  min-width: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item ul li {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
}
.item ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em 0 #fff;
}
.item a.pseudoNested {
  margin: 0.5em 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
Block-level link filling the enclosing &lt;div&gt; element, linking to Stack Overflow.
</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help" class="pseudoNested">Help center</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve" class="pseudoNested">MCVE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/company/about" class="pseudoNested">About SO</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[External JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/htkrsotd/1/).